# Rails: aggregate multiple models into single view (think dashboard)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view, controller, sidebar

I have a Rails 3.1 "blog" type app and my `Post#index` has become a sort of overview (or dashboard or sorts)  into the whole system. The main content is pulled from the **Post** model but a sidebar contains info from an **Event** model, there are other snippets from a **News** model, etc…

Post#index is a busy action that has to populate many instance variable before `/view/posts/index.html.haml` gets a call to render and *then* the many layouts and partials go to work.

Being as some of these other areas are self-contained, so to speak, **I'm wondering if there's a better "Rails way" to approach this?** Perhaps I should be looking at encapsulating the Event sidebar (which is effectively `Event#index`) into some kind of entity that can be re-used perhaps in other views? And, if so, how?

What are the options?

Answer (score 1):

You might checkout

http://cells.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would look into widgetizing it.  A framework that I looked into in the past was: http://apotomo.de/ This provides a nice clean way to widget"ize" as well as callback functionality (Ajax) for specific widgets.